# Copy Text Variable to Clipboard with Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can i copy a text from a JavaScript variable directly to clipboard (without use an html text area)?

I'm already tried this:

```
function fxCopyToClipboard() {

    var varText = "TEXT FOR PASTE";

    varText.select();
    varText.execCommand("copy");

}

<button type="button" onclick="fxCopyToClipboard();">To Clipboard</button>
```

Comment: You can't select JS variables, you've add the text to a textarea element, and select the text from the element.

Comment: Ok, i thought that could be a simple way to do this. TY

Comment: That is a simple way = ). See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard